# Xamarin IOS Navcontroller exception

Tags: c#, ios

I'm running into an exception which I cant resolve myself due to my limited knowledge.
I use a slide out menu in my IOS app in order to navigate through my app ViewControllers.

Whenever I try to navigate to the same ViewController for the second time I run into an exception:

"NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported"

The code looks like this:

```
rolladeButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => {
if (NavController.TopViewController as Rolladecontroller == null)
     NavController.PushViewController(rolladeController, false);
 }
```

The first time I push rolladeButton it works, second time I run into the exception above.
It took me some hours and I came up with this 'solution'

```
lichtButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => {

if (NavController.TopViewController as ContentController == null && pushedlicht == 0) {
NavController.PushViewController(contentController, false);
SidebarController.CloseMenu();
pushedlicht++;
}
else
{                                 
NavController.PopToViewController(contentController, false);
}
```

Now this may look stupid to you, but it gets the job done for me ... at least until I tried adding the third menu button.
Using this solution with currently 3 different ViewController I run into an exception again: 
"Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist."  Even tho I already opened it once.

My guess: the ViewController that was already added previously was deleted from the stack. Because of my variable it tries to push it even tho it does not exist.

Why is (NavController.TopViewController as Rolladecontroller == null) always true? 
Can anyone help me out here on how to do it properly?

For now I use this

```
        lichtButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) => {

            try
            {
                NavController.PushViewController(contentController, false);
                SidebarController.CloseMenu();

            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {                                 

            NavController.PopToViewController(contentController, false);
                SidebarController.CloseMenu();
            }
            startButton.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("start_buttoninactive"), UIControlState.Normal);
            lichtButton.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("licht_buttonactive"), UIControlState.Normal);
            RolladeButton.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("rollade_buttoninactive"), UIControlState.Normal);


            };
```

But it don't think thats the proper way to do it and if I ever wanted to submit it for approval it would probably fail.